# How to convert a HTML webpage to a PDF version

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

I have a website developed using HTML, CSS and javascript/jQuery. I need to convert a webpage to PDF format ( or any other printable version). How can this be done?

Comment: I wanna know whether this can be performed without using PHP

Comment: Sorry, I misread.  I see that your question does not have a PHP tag.  In any case, what are you using server-side?  I don't believe you will be able to do this client-side.

Comment: i believe you could do it with java for client side, or some other server side language

Comment: @user1403848 did you even look at the answers?  Htmldoc (mentioned in the OP) is purely commandline, meaning it can be run from any language that can execute other applications (via PHP's `exec`, Haskell's `system`, etc).  Bottom line:  you will need to use *some* server side language to do it dynamically, even if it isn't PHP.

Comment: JavaScript using Server-side JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

**...any other printable version**. Why not to do just special css and html layout with link like «version for print»?

Comment: I really don't get it. Can you please tell me what it is?

Comment: @ChrisPeters no, he says "convert a webpage to PDF format ( or any other printable version)".  Webpages are printable.

Comment: Got it. Perhaps the title should say "printable" and not "PDF."

Comment: @user1403848 may be this link will explain my idea http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printable_version

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is fantastic and works with any programming language that can run a command line process.  You will have to run the it on the server, but IMHO it is the best way to render PDFs from HTML hands down.

Command line:

```
wkhtmltopdf www.myhomepage.com myhomepage.pdf
```